# Giving an object multiple properties through 'new'?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to give multiple properties in an easy fashion? For example I was trying to do this:

```
object = new Spell( 50, 30, 5, 1, 30, 10 );
object = new Buff( "Armor", 50, 5 );

function Spell( baseDmg, dmgPerLvl, cd, cdPerLvl, cost, costPerLvl ) { 
this.baseDmg = baseDmg;
//...
//etc
// base damage, damage per level, cooldown, cooldown per level, cost, cost per level
}

function Buff( type, amount, duration );
this.type = type;
//etc
}
```

Now these are just two examples, but if I wanted to give many 'properties' to a single object, how would I go about doing it? The way I did it removes the previous new Spell properties and gives it only the Buff attributes. Is there a way to do it like I wrote above without having to write in extremely long arrays everything manually?

And before someone says the code is unreadable, which might be true, I have it entirely written in excel and it's all pretty and very easy to read, I just copy paste all the spells at once. I would prefer sticking with this method if possible.

Thank you very much for any help on the matter, thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Blender, I found a few helpful sources. Would the following solution be a good one or would you say there are better ways for me to do it?

```
object = new Spell( 50, 30, 5, 1, 30, 10 );
Spell.prototype.extendBuff = function( baseCC, ccPerLvl, ccText ) {
        this.baseCC = baseCC;
    this.ccPerLvl = ccPerLvl;
    this.ccText = ccText;
}
object.extendBuff( "Armor", 50, 5 );
```

Comment: `object = new Spell( 50, 30, 5, 1, 30, 10 );` creates a `Spell` object and makes the variable `object` point to it. You have to modify an existing object to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need complex objects one way or the other, here's my favorite way using OOP and inheritance.

```
var Hero = function(name) {
    this.buffs = [];
    this.debuffs = [];
};
Hero.prototype = {
    cast: function(spell, target) {
        if(spell && spell.contructor === Buff) this.buffs.push(spell);
        // etc etc
    }
}

var Spell = function() { /* .... */};
var Buff = function() {
    Spell.apply(this, arguments);
}
Buff.prototype = Object.create(Spell.prototype, {
                constructor: {
                    value: Buff,
                    enumerable: false,
                    writable: true,
                    configurable: true
                }
            });
Buff.prototype.buffType = function() {}; //make sure this is after the Object.create line or it will get overriden

///////

var hero = new Hero('name');
hero.cast(new Spell('attack'), 'enemy');
hero.cast(new Buff('heal'), 'self');
```

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you so much for taking the time to write out an example, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: No problem, I tried to make it simple, let me know if you need any help.